# devise from redirection routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an issue with my routes using devise.

I modified my `devise/sessions/new` view to have both the sign in and the sign_up forms.

Everything works correctly and I can sign in or sign up using either form in the same view (sign_in) if all fields are filled correctly.  However if there is an error in the registration form (missing email, or wrong confirmation password, the user is redirected to the "classic" devise `sign_up` page with a url of `http://0.0.0.0:3000/users` instead of staying in the `users/sign_in` page and showing the errors there.

My routes are the following:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions"}
as :user do
  get 'sign_in', :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

My registration form has the following declaration:

```
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name,  class: "registrtion-form", url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

My application helper sets up the user resource:

```
 def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your can try override RegistrationsController.create method to do that.

```
class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      # respond_with resource
      # custom code to redirect to your sign up form if have an error in the registration form.
      redirect_to ...
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.